# Symfony Cron library failed on Doctrine DBAL error

Tags: php, symfony

I am using this [cron library](https://github.com/Cron/Symfony-Bundle) within my Symfony project. It was working today and after recreating everything from the start (docker, database, vendor folder) and running it again, it crashes.

As it says in documentation I was able to make specific commands and they are persisted in the database.

However when running `bin/console cron:start --blocking` it throws:

> In Manager.php line 60:
>
> Attempted to call an undefined method named "ping" of class
> "Doctrine\DBAL\Connection".

And in my log file:

```
console.ERROR: Error thrown while running command "cron:start --blocking". Message: "Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::ping()" {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to undefined method Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection::ping() at /app/vendor/cron/cron-bundle/Cron/Manager.php:60)","command":"cron:start --blocking","message":"Call to undefined method Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection::ping()"} []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you are using is not compatible with doctrine/dbal >= 3.

You can this to your `composer.json` and reinstall, so that your project uses DBAL 2:

```
"conflict": {
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3.0"
  },
```

Of course, this would depend on you not needing DBAL 3 for anything else.

Although, frankly, I would stop using the `Cron/Symfony-Bundle`. Seems completely unnecessary. Just add your cronjob tasks directly to your crontab. It's not like the bundle frees you from editing crontab, so you might as well put your tasks there.